# My facebook login popup window is not centered, how can I center it?

Tags: facebook, authentication, popup, position

The following code displays a facebook log in link, and works fine in all respects, execpt that when clicked, the facebook login popup window is not centerned (instead it appears awkwardly at the right middle portion of the screen):

```
<div class="provider_logo big" name="facebook">
<div class="inner">




<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    function check_login_status() {

        var FB_API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        FB.init({
            appId:FB_API_KEY, cookie:true,
            status:true, xfbml:true
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                redirect_to_done_page();
            } else {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.session) {
                      redirect_to_done_page();
                    } else {
                      // user cancelled login
                    }
                }, {perms:'email'});
            }
        });
    }

    function redirect_to_done_page() {
        window.location = "/account/facebook/done/";
    }
</script>
<a style="position: relative; top: -8px;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="check_login_status()" perms="email"><img src="/images/facebook.gif" /></a>
```

I tried sticking the var left, and var top options to the beginning of the script to see if that would position the window but it didn't. Any suggestions on how I can modify the above code to center the popup window that appears?

All answers are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your facebook div

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

is within another. Try to place it right underneath your `body` tag!

Comment: It doesn't work for me! and also looks irrelevant to the popup position.